# use facebook sdk for login purpose only

Tags: android-facebook

Is any any way to use Facebook SIGNUP PURPOSE ONLY?

public class MyTestsActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener{

```
private Button mFbLogin;
private TextView mWelcome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_tests);
    setViews();

  }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bFbLogin:
        facebookLogin();
        break;
    }
}
```

???

Comment: This is just sample code..my question in use Facebook login in my app... for that reason i have to import whole sdk..any customization for this...or any alter method to get Facebook login

Comment: As far as I know from my own endeavors and research you must import the whole SDK. There is no way around it. If I am not mistaken that is the purpose of an SDK. If it were and API then you could obviously only use the required ones.

Comment: any other way to use facebook login in android app without use of facebook sdk.....

Comment: read the answer i posted.

Comment: sorry for asking cross questions is there any api for facebook login purpose

Comment: Edited my answer with some links I found but API might be another question.

Answer (score 0):

An SDK is a toolkit that allows you to minimize the amount of code you need to write. This is because it is pre-written. I guess if it is open source and you had the experience could ultimately rewrite it and produce a smaller version of it.

Generally an SDK comes with the API, compiler and various other tools that is why they are so large sometimes.

**EDIT:** Not to sure about FB API's but here are some links that might be helpful.

[Manually build a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2)

[Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)